# AHK, where is the end if? (e.g. #IfWinActive keybinds)

Tags: autohotkey

An excerpt from AHK doc:

> How can a hotkey or hotstring be made exclusive to certain program(s)?
>   In other words, I want a certain key to act as it normally does except
>   when a specific window is active.
>
> The preferred method is #IfWinActive. For example:
>
> ```
> #IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
> ^a::MsgBox You pressed Control-A while Notepad is active.
> ```

This works fine, but the entire rest of the AHK script file is conditionally run only when Notepad is focused.

How do I end the `#IfWinActive`. Better yet, where is the documentation that explains what `#` followed by a thing means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly, the wording is:

> Like the `#IfWin` directives, `#If` is positional: it affects all
>   hotkeys and hotstrings physically beneath it in the script. `#If` and
>   `#IfWin` are also mutually exclusive; that is, only the most recent
>   `#If` or `#IfWin` will be in effect.
>
> To turn off context sensitivity, specify #If or any #IfWin directive
>   but omit all the parameters. For example:
>
> `#If`

So, to essentially put an end-if is to put an empty `#If` after the block previously handled by the opening `#If` statement which would have a condition.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the doc, making your answer better than mine. Have an accept!

Comment: Well, thanks to you for providing the link in the first place. It was confusing to me at first because this language is different from most indeed, so I had to really read the source to ensure I understood it properly.

Answer (score 4):

I found more documentation that fully explains what's going on [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm).

This language does not use an endif. You just write `#if` with no args to specify the negative case.

Terrible language. ;) But, it actually makes sense. This is less expressive from a programming point of view, but since the script is a configuration, 99% of the time you do want to split the binds into equally mutually exclusive zones of the file.